# Widget Scrolling Horizontal ListView

Tags: android, listview, widget

I implemented a listview in my widget (homescreen) but i can only scroll vertically from what i see, is there a way to be able to scroll horizontally ? Thank you !!

Comment: Yep, does'nt work...

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. App widgets have a very limited roster of available UI widgets to use, and there is no option for a horizontally-scrolling list. The closest thing is [`StackView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html).

Comment: Ok it's not i'm looking for, what about a viewflipper with a viewflipperadapter ??

Comment: @samuelzaffran: I would describe it as "swipeable". It looks a bit like a stack of cards, with the top-most card showing fully and two (?) more cards peeking out from behind it. The user can swipe through the cards. It is not a particularly popular widget, as there are more flexible solutions for use in activities. But, for app widgets, since you have few options, it is the closest thing that we have to something that scrolls horizontally.

Comment: @samuelzaffran: "what about a viewflipper with a viewflipperadapter ?" -- that does not offer user input.